# Extracting words using regular expression

Tags: java, regex, json

In the sentence

```
-[Multiple space characters] 1GB – 10TB is $0.19/GB
```

I am trying to extract `1GB`, `10TB`, `%0.19/GB`. 
I tried using the regular expression

```
("-.*(\\d.*)-(\\d[^ ])\\sis\\s(.+)
```

in java but its not working. 
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Gives an exception? Gives different results from what you expected?

Comment: How can you extact `%0.19/GB` from the original string?

Comment: There is an open bracket `(` in the begin of your regex but it doesn't get closed.

Comment: You need to learn about non-greedy capturing. Try adding a question marks where you have a pattern that could match everything (like .* -> .*?)

Comment: [Fairly simple ?](http://regex101.com/r/rF9wV1) `\$?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\/?\s*[KMGT]?B`

Answer (score 1):

Try aiming for the values:

```
String test = "-[Multiple space characters] 1GB – 10TB is $0.19/GB";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\$?[\\d\\.]+/?(G|T)B");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Output:

```
1GB
10TB
$0.19/GB
```